# SqlServerRegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning: Unable to create Azure Synapse Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a Synapse workspace, but the deployment fails with the the following error:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "SqlServerRegionDoesNotAllowProvisioning",
      "message": "Location 'northeurope' is not accepting creation of new Windows Azure SQL Database servers for the subscription 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' at this time."
    }
  ]
}
```

I found a blog post regarding this issue, https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2020/10/synapse-snack-no-new-azure-sql-database.html, but both `Microsoft.Synapse` and `Microsoft.Sql` are registered as resource providers for the subscription. Unregistering and registering them did not help.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am on Free Trial subscription in Australia SouthEast region. The resource providers are registered.

Comment: @user1048175 Try creating the workspace in another location/region. westeurope worked for me. It's not a long-term solution for us, but it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to provision it in another region, as Martin H in the comments suggested.

Comment: You mean region?